# How to correctly free a GHashTable of structs

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, glib

I do not know how to free all memory used, especially for GHashTable.
I have something like this:

```
struct person 
{ 
   char *name;
   int age; 
};

void free_person(gpointer p){
    struct *address person = p;
    if (NULL == person)
        return;
    if(NULL != person->name)
       g_free(person->name);
    g_free(person);
}

And in main:

GHashTable *persons_info list = g_hash_table_new_full(..., ... , NULL, free_person);
struct person * person1 = g_try_malloc0(sizeof(struct person));
person1->age = 20;
char *name = g_strdup("Raul");
person1->name = g->strdup(name);
g_hash_table_insert(list, 2, person1);
 //Now for free...

g_hash_table_destroy(list);
list = NULL;

//Or g_hash_table_unref(list); ?
 
//What about person1 and name? //Should be Fred or just set to Null?

//If I add the following 2 lines sometimes I got sgm fault
free_person(person1):
person1 = NULL;
```

Knows someone the cause of sgm fault if I free variable person 1?

Comment: Is this a typo?  `person1->name = g->strdup(name);`

Comment: Off topic:  `if (NULL == person)` would typically be written `if (person == NULL)`.  (compare the object to the expected value, not the expected value to the object.)

Comment: That's a stylistic choice — some people advocate for `NULL == person` so that the code fails to compile if you accidentally leave out the second `=`.

Comment: Yes, ryyker, was a tipo, I wrote the question from my phone.

Comment: Compilers have been able to warn about unexpected assignments in `if` statements for decades now. `NULL == person` is now purely a stylistic choice rather than a safer choice.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Is not true that NULL == person is faster evaluated then  <some function == NULL? And I kept this way to write if statement in the entire project even if I compare an object.

Comment: I haven’t measured it, but I doubt a compiler would fail to optimise `a == NULL` and `NULL == a` the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If created with `g_hash_table_new_full()`, then `g_hash_table_destroy()` will call the provided key free function and value free function on all the keys and values in the hash table. So you don't have to free them yourself. If you do, then you will be freeing them twice, which is why you get the segfault.

If you used `g_hash_table_new()`, or you gave `NULL` as the key free function and/or value free function, then you do have to free them yourself.

Comment: ptomato, thank for your answer. So, because person1 variable refer to the same memory area, will be free also, understood. It is a good practice to set it on NULL also?